# How to propagate a Tab Bar menu to child views without using a Navigation Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tab Bar Navigation controller, for one of the options available on the tab bar I would like to do the following, the option name in this case is "Order History".

I want to have a simple View Controller with an Activity Indicator to get the data from my Firebase database. Once all the data is gathered, I have an if statement. If the query to Firebase did not return any values I would like to segue to another View Controller that will show the user that he/she has not placed any orders yet. However, if the query to Firebase returns any order history data then I would like to segue to a Table View Controller that will display all of the data in an organized way.

The issue I am having is that I would like to have tab bar menu at the bottom of each of the child views mentioned above. I know I can do this by embedding the first view (the one with the Activity Indicator) inside a Navigation Controller. However, I noticed that once I tap on a different tab bar item and then come back to this tab bar item (the "Order History" tab bar item) it does not show the first view with the Activity Indicator to perform the query to the database once again. Instead, it is going back to the last view presented in the Navigation stack which was the view showing the user that he/she has not placed any orders yet. It is important that the query to the database is performed every time to make sure the data is refreshed every time.

I'd appreciate any input on how to best implement this. I am using the storyboard for all of this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the orderHistoryNavController as is as a viewController in the tab bar. Keep a weak reference to the navigation controller in the tab bar, then override UITabbar:didSelectViewController something like this.

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    orderHistoryNavController.popToRootViewController(NO)
}

This will pop to the activity indicator (even if hidden) anytime a new tab is selected.

Comment: what do you mean by "keep a weak reference to the navigation controller in the tab bar"?

Comment: I keep the weak reference just as a convenience for popping it from didSelectViewController. You can also get it from the 'viewControllers' outlet of the tab bar controller like:

Comment: let orderHistoryNavController = tabBarController.viewControllers[orderHistoryTabIndex]

Comment: For clarification, func didSelect viewController is a UITabBarControllerDelegate method, so I subclass UITabbarController, make it it's own delegate, set the reference to the nav controller at initialization (from the viewControllers outlet in the storyboard), then anytime the tab changes, pop the nav controller reference.